# Any way to get what is effectively a 4 drive mirror in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, raid

I know this doesn't serve that much practical purpose, but I would like to somehow set up a small 400mb partition that is mirrored across 4 drives. I partition using the Disk Management Console, and it only allows you to create a mirror of 2 drives. Is there some way to get around this limitation, or do I need to use different software?

Also, is there any way to do a raid-5 across 4 disks in software (just a subsection of the disk, not the entire physical drive), or do I need to do it in hardware?

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively sure this is possible in linux, but it is not possible in windows without some hackery. Most  hardware raids use the whole drive so would not be suitable for your situation.